# Saving fields to database using Java

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, logic

I have a button inside my application that should be saving to my database. Can anyone tell me if you see anything wrong with my code? It is not saving anything at all.

```
saveButton.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener()
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
              //gets text from texfields and saves to instance variables
              String fname = fNameTextBox.getText();
              String lname = lNameTextBox.getText();
              String email = eMailTextBox.getText();
              String signUpDate = signUpTextBox.getText();

              try
              {
                 //moves cursor to new row
                 //rs.moveToInsertRow();

                 //statement that checks if user enters all letters      
                 if(fname.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
                 {
                    //statement that checks if user enters all letters      
                    if(lname.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) 
                    {
                       //statement and actions if user enters a '.'
                       if(email.contains("."))
                       {
                          //gets last period in email
                          int emailDotCheck = email.lastIndexOf(".");

                          //substring to period in variable "emailDotCheck"
                          String extensionCheck = email.substring(emailDotCheck);

                          //statement and actions if user doesn't enter email correctly                 
                          if(!email.contains("@") || !extensionCheck.matches("\\.[a-z]{3}"))
                          {
                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter email in correct format!");
                             eMailTextBox.setText("");                                       
                          }

                          else
                          {  
                             //instance variables
                             int month = 100;
                             int day = 100;
                             int year = 10000;

                             //statement and actions if user enters 'signUpDate' in correct format    
                             if(signUpDate.matches("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}"))
                             {
                                //gets substring of instance variables
                                String monthStr = signUpDate.substring(0,2);
                                String dayStr = signUpDate.substring(3,5);
                                String yearStr = signUpDate.substring(6);

                                //parsing intstance variables to Integers         
                                month = Integer.parseInt(monthStr);                       
                                day = Integer.parseInt(dayStr);
                                year = Integer.parseInt(yearStr);

                                //statements and actions if user doesn't enter date in correct format   
                                if(month > 12 || day > 31 || year > 2100)
                                {
                                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter date in correct format! (dd/MM/yyyy)");
                                   signUpTextBox.setText("");
                                } 

                                else
                                { 
                                  //String sql4 = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Fname, Lname, [E_mail], [Sign_up_date]) VALUES (fname, lname, email, signUpDate)";

                                    //execute query, assigning specified record in db to 'rs4'
                                   //rs4 = st.executeQuery(sql4);                                       

                                   rs.moveToInsertRow();

                                   //inserts record into db                                     
                                   rs.updateString("Fname", fname);
                                   rs.updateString("Lname", lname);
                                   rs.updateString("E-mail", email);
                                   rs.updateString("Sign_up_date", signUpDate);

                                   //inserts data into db      
                                   rs.insertRow();

                                   //closes statement variable so there won't be a gap in db                                       
                                   st.close();

                                   //closes result set variable so there won't be a gap in db
                                   rs.close();

                                   //create new statement to help us gain access to table in db
                                   st = con.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, rs.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

                                   //statement that selects everything from our table
                                   String sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1";

                                   //execute query, assigning all records in db to 'rs'
                                   rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

                                   //gets next row in db
                                   rs.next();

                                   //sets text in text fields to specified fields in db
                                   fNameTextBox.setText(rs.getString("Fname"));
                                   lNameTextBox.setText(rs.getString("Lname"));
                                   eMailTextBox.setText(rs.getString("E_mail"));
                                   fNameTextBox.setText(rs.getString("Sign_up_date"));
                                }
                             }

                             //statement and actions if user does enter date in correct format        
                             else
                             {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter date in correct format! (dd/MM/yyyy)");
                                signUpTextBox.setText("");
                             }
                          }
                       }

                       //statement and actions if user doesn't enter email in correct format        
                       else
                       {
                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter email in correct format!");
                          eMailTextBox.setText("");
                       }

                    }

                    //statement and actions if user doesnt enter last name in correct format        
                    else
                    {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter last name in correct format!");
                       lNameTextBox.setText("");
                    }
                 }

                 //statement and actions if user doesn't enter first name in correct format       
                 else
                 {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter first name in correct format!");
                    fNameTextBox.setText("");
                 }
              }
              catch(Exception ex)
              {

              }         
           }          
        });
```

Comment: Are you seeing any logs related to the database save operation ? That would be the first place to look at for any problems.

Comment: Did you try to DEBUG your code?

Comment: Please do not swallow exceptions. `catch(Exception ex){}`.

Comment: @Shankar I have debugged it and could not find the error...

Comment: Put an `ex.printStackTrace()` inside your catch block and try running your code again.Do you encounter any exceptions ?

Comment: javaGeek: Did you get any error? Did you debug every line? What did insertRow and executeQuery return?

Comment: I have, I get a "Column not found" error

Comment: @Shankar hey both return nothing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by reporting any errors that are encountered

```
          catch(Exception ex)
          {

          }
```

a catch block that silently consumes errors is usually a bad idea.

Second, use a debugger, step through the code and see what's going on. Attempting to solve a problem like this by desk-checking, ie. just reading the code is usually very inefficient. Here we don't have key information, such as whether we have confidence that

```
  rs.moveToInsertRow();
```

can be expected to work - we can't see how rs gets its value. Many database problems only occur at runtime, there's a misconfiguration of the database connection or an attempted insert collides with existing data. Hence it's only by understanding what your code is doing in your test run that the problem can be solved.

Here I'd guess that printing out some diagnistics in your catch will be really helpful, and otherwise stepping in a debugger (or adding trace statements) will get you there.

Comment: That's not an answer.

Comment: When you step in the debugger you will surely see on which line the exception is thrown. My guess is that one of your lines like  rs.updateString("E-mail", email); has the column name misspelled

Comment: and mttdbrd, the question almost certainly cannot be answered as it stands (we now know that code and db schema don't match, but that's one of many possible problems) but we can offer a process by which the answer can be found, which I contend is actually more useful.

Comment: @djna would it be more helpful if I posted all of my code?

Comment: I figured my issue out and this post was most helpful, I had a "-" where I needed an "_". Thank you for pointing that out @djna